# Alter a column name in a view in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, view, rename

I have a table, x, and a view, x_view, that is based on x, in a PostgreSQL database.

x:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
A double precision
);
```

x_view:

```
CREATE VIEW x_view AS
 SELECT x.A;
```

I renamed a column in x from A to B.

```
ALTER TABLE x RENAME COLUMN A to B
```

When I then look at the definition of the view, I see the following:

```
SELECT x.B AS A from x;
```

When I do a "SELECT * FROM x_view", the column that should now be labeled B is still labeled A.

Why does the view not automatically change the name of the column when I execute "SELECT * FROM x_view"? Is there any way to force it to do so, besides having to drop and recreate the view?

Comment: can you show the DDL for your table and view?

Comment: Aah, now I understand.  That is quite a pickle.  Unfortunately, because objects can be bound to x_view, I don't think this is possible without dropping and re-creating the view.  I hope someone proves me wrong.  The issue, for example, is if you have another view that is reading x_view and counting on there being a column a, you will notice when you try to change the view it won't let you until you reconcile the dependencies on A.  Again, I hope someone else knows a way that I don't.

Comment: Yeah, PostgreSQL doesn't know how to do this yet. Patches are welcome ;) but at the moment all you can do is drop and recreate the view.

Answer (score 12):

You can use `ALTER TABLE x_view RENAME COLUMN A to B`
 to rename your view column.

Source: @Peter Eisentraut's answer [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/596/20727) and I checked on my database.

Comment: Postgres 12 requires ALTER TABLE, but 13+ can ALTER VIEW {view} RENAME COLUMN.